Angle between points of a grid, on the surface of a hypersphere
I face a rather particular problem, I looked it up but perhaps my mathematical background is lacking, in order to extrapolate an answer from the existing threads. Assume the unit hypersphere $U^d = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid \|x\| = 1\}$. We pick a sampling of this hypersphere $B^d$. A way to do this is to compute points on the surface of the hypersphere in hyperspherical coordinates. Let $\theta \in (0, \pi)$. We define the family of vectors,
\begin{equation*}
 B^d(\theta) = \left\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d \left\vert ~~ \mathbf{x} = (1, k_1\theta, \dots, k_{d-1}\theta), k_i \in \left[ \frac{\pi}{\theta}\right], i \in [d-1] \right.\right\}.
\end{equation*}
Assume $\mathbf{x} \in B^d(\theta)$. Moreoever, let $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x} + (0, \theta, \dots, \theta)$. I want to compute the angle $\measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$.
Let $\mathbf{e}^i = (0, 0, \dots, 0, \theta, 0, \dots, 0)$. Naturally, $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x} + \sum_{i=1}^{d-1} \mathbf{e}^i$. Moreoever, I think $\measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{e}^i) = \theta$. Thus, using the triangular inequality for angles we have,
\begin{equation}
 \measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \leq (d-1)\theta \quad (1).
\end{equation}
The above upper bound only works for $\theta \leq \frac{\pi}{d-1}$. Can we have a more meaningful upper bound of $\measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$? Can we have an exact computation of $\measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$?
Thanks in advance for any answers. Guiding me to an existing answer is also appreciated.

You are mistaken about the claim that $$
\measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{e}^i) = \theta.
$$
To see this, consider the special case $d = 3$, where we have latitude and longitude coordinates. Let's say that $e^1$ is longitude and $e^2$ is latitude.
There's some latitude representing the north pole. (It might be $\pi/2$, it might be $\pi$, and I can't bring myself to read yet another description of generalized polar coordinates and find out which one your reference uses.) Let's call it $b$. Now consider the two points
$$
x = (0, b)
$$
and
$$
y = (0 + \pi/4, b)
$$
In this case, $x$ and $y$ are the same point -- the north pole -- and the angle between these two points is $0$, not $\pi/4$.
The problem here is that distance in the 'coordinate space' (i.e., measuring latitude and longitude distances) is very different from distance on the sphere itself (or "difference in angle subtended at the center of the sphere"). That's not really a fault of the coordinate system --- there is NO 'continuous' coordinate system on the sphere that maps coordinate distances to sphere-distances, a problem/result known as 'the mapmaker's dilemma'.
I'm sorry to be disappointing, but I'm pretty certain that if you thoroughly grasp the challenges present in the case of the unit sphere in 3-space, you'll be about 90 percent of the way to understanding the more general case.

Thank you very much for your response and your insight. I now understand why $\measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{e}^i) \neq \theta$. On the other hand, isn't the case that $\measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{e}^i) \leq \theta$? If the latter holds, then my (naive) upper bound in (1) should hold. Have I understand this correctly?

Another question, can I use a naive generalization for the Pythagorean theorem for spheres in this n-dimensional sphere? Namely, $\cos[\measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})] = \Pi_{i = 1}^{d-1} \cos[\measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{e}^i)]$?

I don't offhand know the answers to either of those questions. I'm sorry. I suspect that the first one is correct, and might be proved using something like $|\sin t| \le |t|$ for $-\pi/2 \le t \le \pi/2$.  The second generalization seems unlikely, but then again, I didn't even know that there was a Pythagorean Theorem for spheres, so my guessing abilities shouldn't be trusted here.
